# How to use value passed to views_embed_view as a filter?

Tags: 7, views

I want to embed a View in a node template. I understand that I can use views_embed view to do that, and pass values to it.

```
$my_arg = $node->nid; //the nid of the node that I want to use as filter
print views_embed_view('my_test_view', 'block_2', $my_arg);
```

How can I use that value as a filter ? I want that view to list nodes that have a field with the same value as the passed to the function

Comment: Aren't "Arguments" essentially same as exposed "Filters"? I'm not really understanding your question, so if you could expand on it with examples it would be helpful for people to help you.

Comment: Your code looks good. Check (via the views UI) that your view 'my_test_view' accepts an argument

Comment: Arguments are called contextual filters in the UI of Views 3.  Typically their values come from the page path. Exposed filters are regular filters that are exposed through a form. Their values will also appear in the URL but as GET variables.

Comment: So, to return to the original question, the view needs to have a contextual filter that accepts the field value. Take care if this view is going to be executed across a lot of data, as the resulting SQL will require a full table scan in the worst case.

Comment: That final argument should be an array, by the way:

`views_embed_view('my_test_view', 'block_2', array($my_arg));`

Comment: "the view needs to have a contextual filter that accepts the field value"

That did the trick. Thanks, @Alfred Armstrong

Answer (score 5):

The value you pass as last argument to `views_embed_view` is not passed to the Views' *filters*, but to the view's *contextual filters*  (also known as *arguments*). Contextual Filters are like filters, expect they take external input (from the URL when viewed as a page or from the arguments passed to functions such as `views_embed_view`). You can learn more about contextual filters here: http://drupal.org/node/1578558

Answer (score 0):

As mention by Alfred Armstrong, I needed to have to have a contextual filter that accepts the field value. From there, it was good to go.

Comment: We used to call 'contextual filters' 'argument' in views 2 and D6 :) that's why it's confusing